# Warnings while using matplotlib

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, warnings

I am trying to run this code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK3Cairo')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,6*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

and I get these warnings:

> (tryMe.py:585): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3415:30:
> The style property GtkButton:image-spacing is deprecated and shouldn't
> be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
>
> (tryMe.py:585): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3416:29:
> The style property GtkButton:inner-border is deprecated and shouldn't
> be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

I can see the plots, but how can I solve or suppress these warnings? I am using Linux Mint 19. I don't understand what exactly is causing these warnings to originate

Comment: It comes from the backend you are using. Is there any reason to use the Cairo backend and not another, such as TkAgg (`matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`)?

Comment: You can also have a look at `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='the_message')` to keep using this backend but silence the warning.

Comment: [SOLVED] Thanks. Seems like a missing package problem. Changed the virtual environment and installed required backends and packages using conda. Works fine.